# Does it make sense to eject a project from create react app and "take back control"

Tags: reactjs, configuration, single-page-application, create-react-app

Create react app is an awesome way to setup a new react project. However i can see it forces certain decisions onto you that come baked in, eg using Jest rather than other test runners such as karma/mocha. As I am setting up a new greenfield project with React, am trying to identify is the best practise to stay with it and accept certain constraints or do most teams end up ejecting and in the parlance of brexit "take back control" and what the reasoning is.

Answer (score 2):

`create-react-app` actually has a lot of sensible defaults and make it an ideal starting point. But they also regularly update things to stay in sync with where the industry is going. So that's great. And it is maintained by some of the same people responsible for React.

The biggest drawback (and strength) is that it doesn't include many other libraries. You have to add those yourself.

But if you do that you occasionally find that you need to add or tweak a small thing in the Babel/Webpack config.

Luckily there is a middle group. Using libraries like `react-app-rewired` (https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) allows you to make small changes to the Webpack config without ejecting just yet.

Once you do that you will want to be very careful with upgrading `react-scripts`. Because every time you do it might break your Webpack changes to their script.
But only once that pain is too much would I consider ejecting.